# MongoDB Query that will $project document values in horizontal format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to create a query that will project or show the field in HORIZONTAL format. Below is my sample collection and the expected output. BTW, Im also using jaspersoft studio to create the report but i think my output should be done in mongodb query. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

```
"_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9b9"),
    "observationvalues" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9c3"),
            "name" : "Systolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "88.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9c2"),
            "name" : "Diastolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "66.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9c1"),
            "name" : "Weight",
            "resultvalue" : "90.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9c5"),
            "name" : "Height",
            "resultvalue" : null
        }
    ],
    "createdat" : ISODate("2021-07-01T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-01T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "statusflag" : "A"

"_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e8b8"),
    "observationvalues" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9b3"),
            "name" : "Systolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "84.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9b2"),
            "name" : "Diastolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "63.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9b1"),
            "name" : "Weight",
            "resultvalue" : "99.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9b5"),
            "name" : "Height",
            "resultvalue" : 172.00
        }
    ],
    "createdat" : ISODate("2021-07-02T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-02T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "statusflag" : "A"



"_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e7b7"),
    "observationvalues" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9a3"),
            "name" : "Systolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "81.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9a2"),
            "name" : "Diastolic BP",
            "resultvalue" : "65.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9a1"),
            "name" : "Weight",
            "resultvalue" : "96.00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ddc6f44c893c117141e9a5"),
            "name" : "Height",
            "resultvalue" : 165.00
        }
    ],
    "createdat" : ISODate("2021-07-03T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-03T13:45:24.679Z"),
    "statusflag" : "A",
```

The expected Output will be:

```
{"createdat" : "2021-07-01T13:45:24.679Z", "Systolic BP" : 88.00 ,"Diastolic BP" : 66.00 ,"Weight": 90.00 ,"Height":null }
{"createdat" : "2021-07-01T13:45:24.679Z", "Systolic BP" : 84.00 ,"Diastolic BP" : 63.00 ,"Weight": 99.00 ,"Height":172.00 }
{"createdat" : "2021-07-03T13:45:24.679Z", "Systolic BP" : 81.00 ,"Diastolic BP" : 65.00 ,"Weight": 96.00 ,"Height":165.00 }
```

I have created my query but it is not having the output in one line grouped for each createdat field

```
{ 
$project : {
    _id: {
            "systolic":  {"$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$name","Systolic BP" ] }, "$resultvalue","" ] },
            "diastolic":  {"$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$name","Diastolic BP" ] }, "$resultvalue","" ] },
            "weight":  {"$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$name","Weight" ] }, "$resultvalue","" ] },
            "height":  {"$cond": [ { "$eq": ["$name","Height" ] }, "$resultvalue","" ] },
            "create": "$createdat"
        }

            }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected data output could be done like this: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HFeMbjT4h8r)

```
[
    {
        "$project": {
            "createdat": 1,
            "rows": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$observationvalues",
                        "in": {
                            "k": "$$this.name",
                            "v": {
                                "$convert": {
                                    "input": "$$this.resultvalue",
                                    "to": "double",
                                    "onError": null,
                                    "onNull": null
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "rows.create": "$createdat"
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$rows"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "Systolic BP": 84.00
        }
    }
]
```

To get them in one line you should look for some JSON formater.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works if the collection or array is not $unwind. What if I need to put $match? For example I need only to return the value for height and Weight? BTW, I already incorporate your code in my query

Comment: Can I also convert $$this.resultvalue to integer? currently it is returning string values.

Comment: @JayvenJavier  added an example match and the number conversion. You could convert the values to whatever you want. [Convert Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#mongodb-expression-exp.-convert)

Comment: Also, the values are returned as strings, because they are declared as strings. Maybe you could store them as numbers too.

Comment: @JayvenJavier ReEdited cos the match agg was incorrect. You could add a match stage where you want, in this case is added at the end with the new format. Later I migth do a filter to match the expected documents before mapping them.